# how to count the time from LOW to HIGH pin level in python

Tags: python, time, count

i have this code right here:

```
import datetime
import time
import math
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(20,GPIO.IN)
input = GPIO.input(20)

#initialise a previous input variable to 0 (assume button not pressed last)

prev_input = 0
D = 0.66       #wheel diameter
while True:
#take a reading
input = GPIO.input(20)

#if last was low and this one's high, do:

if ((not prev_input) and input):

  end_time = datetime.datetime.now()             # timestamp
  s = time.mktime(end_time.timetuple())  
  #delta_time = s - c                            #difference of times ???

  #instant_speed = ((math.pi * D) / delta_time)  #moment speed

  print 'magnet touched', s

#if LOW, do:

if ( input == 0 ):

 start_time = datetime.datetime.now()    #timestamp
 c = time.mktime(start_time.timetuple()) 

 print 'not touched', c

#update previous input
prev_input = input
#slight pause to debounce
#time.sleep(0.05)
```

I want to count the time passed since the LOW level of the PIN20 changed to HIGH and then use the difference of time in my further speed countings.
This is a code for a reed switch, what i am planning to do is to make it as a speed counter.

Could anyone give me a hint of how to calculate the time? Thank you.

Comment: Use another `datetime.datetime.now()`?

Comment: next time try to only give the code you are having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

So you just put the time when the pin went to high in a variable. when you need to access the time you get the current time minus the variable you declared earlier.

```
if input:
    time_since_high = datetime.datetime.now()
time_passed = datetime.datetime.now() - time_since_high
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import time
while input == 0:
  start = time.time()

while input == 1:
  stop = time.time()

# Calculate elapsed time
elapsed = stop - start
```

This will poll the GPIO pin to see if the input changes from LOW to HIGH. It will then calculate the time it takes to go from LOW to HIGH. The time difference is given in seconds.